# Mongodb aggregation - replicate document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to generate a navigation out of an article collection. I have articles in different languages. The problem I have is that the articles marked with an '*' in the lang field should appear in every language. So i would have to replicate and insert them in every navigation. Would that be possible with the aggregation framework?

```js
[
    { "$match": { "active":{ "$gte" :0 } }},
    { "$project":{ 
        "_id" :1,
        "lang":"$lang", 
        "topNav": { "name": "$title", "link": "$path" }
    }},
    { "$group": { 
        "_id":{ "lang":'$lang'},
         "topNav":{ "$push": "$topNav" }
    }},
    { "$out": "navigation" }
]
```

Final Array

```js
[
    { 
         "_id" :{ "lang":"en" },
         "topNav":[
             {
                 "name": "Main Article",
                 "link": "/"
             },
             {
                 "name": "Admin",
                 "link": "/admin"
             }
         ]
     },{ 
         "_id" :{ "lang":"de" },
         "topNav":[
             {
                 "name": "Main Article De",
                 "link": "/"
             },
             {
                 "name": "Admin",
                 "link": "/admin"
             }
         ]
     }
]
```

Articles

```js
{
"_id" : ObjectId("1"),
"path" : "/",
"title" : "Main Article",
"content" : "Main Site!",
"lang" : "en",
},{
"_id" : ObjectId("2"),
"path" : "/admin",
"title" : "Admin",
"content" : "Admin Site!",
"lang" : "*",
},{
"_id" : ObjectId("3"),
"path" : "/",
"title" : "Main Article De",
"content" : "Main Site! De",
"lang" : "de",
}
```

Comment: You should show some sample documents as well as your expected result to explain what you mean. It will help you get an answer. Edit your question.

Comment: I added the example documents to the main post.

Comment: Your sample result seems a bit misleading. Don't you actually mean that you want "Admin Site" to always appear and then only other items matching your currently selected language? That seems logical but your result shows items from two languages and no Admin data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with the aggregation framework, or at least not possible without great difficulty and/or schema modifications. The issue is that every document, as it is passed through an aggregation stage, produces 0 or 1 document "upserts", where updates can happen with the `$group` stage, except for the `$unwind` operator which can produce copies of a document except that the unwound array field has a particular element as its value.

However, if feasible, you could try something like changing `lang` to an array of languages, putting all possible languages in an array on each * doc in place of *:

```
> db.articles.insert({ 
        "_id" : 0, 
        "path" : "/", 
        "title" : "Main Article", 
        "content" : "Main Site!", 
        "lang" : ["en"] 
    })
> db.articles.insert({
        "_id" : 1,
        "path" : "admin",
        "title" : "admin",
        "content" : "admin site",
        "lang" : ["en", "de"]
    }
> db.articles.insert({ 
        "_id" : 2, 
        "path" : "/", 
        "title" : "Main Article De", 
        "content" : "Main Site! De", 
        "lang" : ["de"] 
    })
```

and then a pipeline like the following does what you want:

```
> db.articles.aggregate([
    { "$unwind" : "lang" },
    { "$project":{ 
        "_id" :1,
        "lang": "$lang", 
        "topNav": { "name": "$title", "link": "$path" }
    }},
    { "$group": { 
        "_id":{ "lang":'$lang'},
         "topNav":{ "$push": "$topNav" }
    }},
])

{
    "_id" : { "lang" : "de" },
    "topNav" : [
        {
            "name" : "Main Article De",
            "link" : "/"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Admin",
            "link" : "/admin"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : { "lang" : "en" },
    "topNav" : [
        {
            "name" : "Main Article",
            "link" : "/"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Admin",
            "link" : "/admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Clearly, this isn't ideal, especially if you have a dynamic set of languages to support. It does give you the bonus of being able to tag articles with arbitrary languages and then group them correctly :D

For your use case, I'd guess the numbers of objects involved are small enough that you'll be fine handling the * case in client code, so all this is just for curiosity/posterity.